# Hidden select box

Tags: html, jquery

I want to select and show another based on what selected and its working, my problem is that I want to show the select box with `class sub` instead being hidden.

I tried to remove `$sub.hide();` and `.show();` but if I try it breaks the whole code and stop working because main selectbox have to be selected to bring other selectbox but I want other select box to be not hidden

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select>
    <!--This is main selectbox.-->
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option>ONE</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
  </select>
  <select class="sub">
    <!--another selectbox for option one.-->
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test1</option>
  </select>
  <select class="sub">
    <!--another selectbox for option two.-->
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test2</option>
  </select>
  <select class="sub">
    <!--another selectbox for option three.-->
    <option>test3</option>
    <option>test3</option>
  </select>
  <select class="sub">
    <!--another selectbox for option four.-->
    <option>test4</option>
    <option>test4</option>
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var $sub = $('select.sub');
    $('select').first().change(function() {
      $sub.hide();
      if (this.selectedIndex > 0)
        $sub.eq(this.selectedIndex - 1).show();
    }).change();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're describing.  If you remove `$sub.hide()` then the other `<select>` elements are not hidden.  (Which then makes all of the JavaScript shown here moot, so the whole thing can be removed.)  What "breaks the whole code and stops working"?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is i dont want  <select class="sub"> to be hidden on default

Comment: [Then remove `$sub.hide();`.](https://jsfiddle.net/7j95oq1y/)  But the question implies that you already knew that, so what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `select.sub` to be hidden by default, then you shouldn't be triggering the change in your onchange event listener. Which doesn't really make sense anyway.

You are listening for the change event, but also triggering the change event.

Remove the `.change()` at the end of the event listener.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
        <!--This is main selectbox.-->
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option>ONE</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
        <option>four</option>
    </select>
    <select class="sub">
        <!--another selectbox for option one.-->
        <option>test1</option>
        <option>test1</option>
    </select>
    <select class="sub">
        <!--another selectbox for option two.-->
        <option>test2</option>
        <option>test2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="sub">
        <!--another selectbox for option three.-->
        <option>test3</option>
        <option>test3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="sub">
        <!--another selectbox for option four.-->
        <option>test4</option>
        <option>test4</option>
    </select>    
        <script type="text/javascript">    
    var $sub = $('select.sub');
    $('select').first().change(function () {    
        $sub.hide();
        if (this.selectedIndex > 0)
           $sub.eq(this.selectedIndex - 1).show();
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```